# ag-grid column headers stacked to the left

Tags: ag-grid

Only the first column header is being drawn correctly, all subsequent items in the columnDef array are drawn below it. If I populate the table with data, all column data is stacked to the left as well.

Here's what it looks like; the gray band in the row, below Country is actually moving down, as part of the framework.setTimeout() function in ag-grid.js.

[image]

The JS looks like:

```
gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Country', field: 'country' },
    { headerName: 'City', field: 'city' },
    { headerName: 'Jan', field: 'jan_act' },
    { headerName: 'Feb', field: 'feb_act' },
    { headerName: 'Mar', field: 'mar_act' },
    { headerName: 'Apr', field: 'apr_act' },
    { headerName: 'May', field: 'may_act' }];

var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

I'm using `ag-grid.noStyle.js` v7.0.2 and think I have all dependencies loaded correctly for ag-grid. Am not using `React` or `Angular`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it! It's the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.

Problem was immediately resolved by changing the height of my div to pixel based, not %, e.g.

```
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 400px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
```

Found it by going back to absolute basics after the [JavaScript](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-javascript-data-grid/) Datagrid example also failed to work.

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)