# Grid broken with Angular-CLI and Webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ag-grid

As of angular-compiler version `1.0.0-Beta.19-3`, angular version `2.2.3`, and ag-grid version `7.0.2` the column headers stack on top of each other like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008182/ag-grid-column-headers-stacked-to-the-left/41008430#41008430) stackoverflow post.

The grey line at the bottom of the grid keeps moving downwards and the data is stacked on top of itself in one column.

[image]

I am having this problem with the Angular 2 component version of the grid. Tomorrow I will be trying the pure Javascript version.

Has anyone here successfully got the grid to work in Angular 2 using the AngularCLI with Webpack?

Comment: I have gotten it working, are you including the CSS file in `angular-cli.json` under `app[0].styles`?

Comment: I didn't try that yet. I just imported the CSS file in my styles.css file. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Brocco do you have a sample webpack and angular-cli config that you'd be willing to share for this?

Comment: @SeanLandsman I posted my setup as an answer below

Comment: Just a quick note here - setting up ag-grid with angular-cli was pretty straightforward (h/t to @brocco) in the end. There will be a new project example available from tomorrow @ the ag-grid-ng2-example repo that illustrates this

Comment: @SeanLandsman Thanks! ping me on twitter when that's up... I'll tweet about it once you have it up....  https://twitter.com/Brocco

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I've followed to get ag-grid working with Angular

- `npm i ag-grid --save`
- `npm i ag-grid-ng2 --save`
- In `angular-cli.json` under apps -> styles:

  - `../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css`
  - `../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-bootstrap.css`
- In your `NgModule`

  - `import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';`
  - `@NgModule({ imports: [ ... AgGridModule.withComponents([])...`
- In your component's template:

  - `<ag-grid-ng2 ...`

Comment: After I try this later today if it works for me I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Now my grid has disappeared. I'll work with it more soon and see if I can get things working.

Answer (score 1):

There are now examples or using ag-Grid with either SystemJS, Webpack or AngularCLI - the examples project can be found here: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example

h/t to @brocco for the pointers above

Answer (score 0):

A couple of extra points.

In @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2, the file you want is ".angular-cli.json"; note the beginning dot. It is in the project root directory. Use ls -a.

If you are running "ng serve", you must stop and restart it for the changes to go into effect.